# O notation and merging two already sorted arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

I've been told to merge two already sorted arrays, of different sizes, A and B into an array, C in linear time.

By linear time, I understood that the time complexity of this algorithm has to be O(n). Later on, I was also told to perform sorting while merging the arrays.

One idea I had was to create an algorithm where you have two pointers in both arrays, pointing at the smallest element. The smallest element which is pointed at would go into the new array. When one array is exhausted, the remaining elements of the other array are copied into the new array.

Since I just started programming a few months ago, I have found this difficult to implement and hence I decided to perform Merge Sort (MS) since it's the most similar to the above-mentioned algorithm. However, I'm concerned with the time complexity of MS itself - O(nlogn)

However, given that the two arrays would be already sorted, would the time complexity for MS be reduced or will it remain the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Merge sort performs a merge of two sorted arrays several times. You just need to perform it once so can just use a single merge step from mergesort.

Comment: The normal usage of the term "merge" is to merge two already sorted arrays, and "sorting while merging" would be a conflict in the meaning of "merge". The should be "sort before merging", in which case, any sort algorithm could be used to sort the 2 arrays.  If the ideal is to implement a merge sort, than a bottom up approach, which is the original approach, treats a single array of n elements a n sorted runs of size 1 element each, and each pass merges even and odd runs to double their size and halve the number of runs until a single sorted run is produced.

Comment: The average and maximum time complexity of merge sort is `O(n*log n)`. However, since you only need to perform a single merge step instead of recursive merging, the time complexity is only `O(n)`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Does this also apply if I have two different sized arrays which are first merged then sorted with MS?

Comment: @gann: Whether the two arrays are of the same size or not doesn't matter. If the arrays are already sorted, then you can merge and sort at the same time, using an algorithm with a time complexity of `O(n)`. This algorithm would be the same as a single merge sort step. However, if the two arrays are not sorted, you will have to do a simple unsorted merge and then a full merge sort afterwards, which has a time complexity of `O(n*log n)`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel This answers my question. If you would put this as an answer, I would kindly accept it :)

Comment: @gann: Thanks for your offer, but I don't think that I can improve upon the already existing answer. Feel free to accept it.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Your loss, I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your task is to implement the merge phase of the mergesort algorithm. mergesort has a complexity of **O(N.log(N))** to sort the dataset, but each merge phase takes linear time proportional to the length of the merged set.

Here is pseudo code for this:

```
merge(array a, array b into array c)
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < len(a) and j < len(b)) {
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        } else {
            c[k++] = b[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < len(a)) {
        c[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j < len(b)) {
        c[k++] = b[j++];
    }
}
```

The complexity is linear as each step in each of the loops copies an element into the `c` array, for a total of `len(a) + len(b)` steps.

Answer (score 1):

> merge two already sorted arrays, of different sizes, A and B into an
> array, C in linear time.

```
int *mergeArrays(const int *array1, const int *array2, size_t size1, size_t size2, int asc)
{
    int *result = malloc((size1 + size2) * sizeof(*array1));
    size_t index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
    size_t i;


    for(i = 0; i < size1 + size2 && index1 < size1 && index2 < size2; i++)
    {   
        if(asc)
        {
            if(array1[index1] > array2[index2]) result[i] = array2[index2++];
            else result[i] = array1[index1++];
        }
        else
        {
            if(array1[index1] > array2[index2]) result[i] = array2[index2++];
            else result[i] = array1[index1++];
        }
    }
    if(index1 == size1) memcpy(result + i, array2 + index2, sizeof(result) * (size2 - index2));
    if(index2 == size2) memcpy(result + i, array1 + index1, sizeof(result) * (size1 - index1));
    return result;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PY8Ysv319

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

void sort(int *array, size_t size)
{
    qsort(array, size, sizeof(array[1]), cmpfunc);
}

int *mergeArrays(const int *array1, const int *array2, size_t size1, size_t size2, int asc)
{
    int *result = malloc((size1 + size2) * sizeof(*array1));
    size_t index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
    size_t i;


    for(i = 0; i < size1 + size2 && index1 < size1 && index2 < size2; i++)
    {   
        if(asc)
        {
            if(array1[index1] > array2[index2]) result[i] = array2[index2++];
            else result[i] = array1[index1++];
        }
        else
        {
            if(array1[index1] > array2[index2]) result[i] = array2[index2++];
            else result[i] = array1[index1++];
        }
    }
    if(index1 == size1) memcpy(result + i, array2 + index2, sizeof(result) * (size2 - index2));
    if(index2 == size2) memcpy(result + i, array1 + index1, sizeof(result) * (size1 - index1));
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    size_t size1 = rand() % 20, size2 = rand() % 20;
    int *mergedArray;

    if(size1 < 5) size1 += 5;
    if(size2 < 5) size2 += 5;

    int array1[size1], array2[size2];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        array1[i] = rand();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++) 
        array2[i] = rand();
    sort(array1, size1);
    sort(array2, size2);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        printf("array1[%2zu] = %d\n", i, array1[i]);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++)
        printf("array2[%2zu] = %d\n", i, array2[i]);

    mergedArray = mergeArrays(array1, array2, size1, size2, 1);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size2 + size1; i++)
        printf("result[%2zu] = %d\n", i, mergedArray[i]);
}
```

You need to add memory allocation checks, NULL pointer checks etc.